# Does Drupal's theme('table') works in email body?

Tags: 7, emails

I want to send the list of some of the node information in email to users.

I have created table of information using theme('table') function. Now I want to send this table to email to user.

Is it possible to send theme('table') using Email ?

Will it work when user will see the information in Email ?

I am sending table structure in Email, is this possible to achieve it?

I have attached the relevant code to generate table and send mail.

```
$header = array(
            array('data' => t('Title'), 'field' => 'n.title'),
            array('data' => t('Author'), 'field' => 'u.name'),
    );
    $query = db_select('node', 'n');
    $query->leftjoin('users', 'u', 'u.uid = n.uid');
    $query->fields('n',array('title', 'created', 'nid', 'type'))
    ->fields('u',array('name', 'uid'))
    ->fields('b',array('body_value'))
    ->fields('c',array('subject'));
    $query->condition(db_or()->condition('n.type', 'post', '=')->condition('n.type', 'forum', '='));
    $query->condition('n.uid', $user->uid, '=');
    $result = $query->execute();
    $rows = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        if($row->subject) {
            $titlerow = l($row->subject, 'node/'. $row->nid).'</br>'. $row-
        }
        $rows[] = array( $titlerow,
                t('Reply Posted by: ').l($row->name, 'user/'. $row->uid)
        );
    }
    $params = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows, array('class' => array('ajax-sample-table'))));
    $language = language_default();
    $send = TRUE;
    $result = drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params, $from, $send);
    if ($result['result'] == TRUE) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Your message has been sent.'));
    }
```

Comment: I think this can help you. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28431/drupal-mail-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read [drupal_mail() in HTML](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28431/drupal-mail-in-html) for how to output HTML in an email sent with `drupal_mail()`.

As you are outputting links, I will add a note about that. By default [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) outputs relative links that outside the website are not much useful. You need to force Drupal to output absolute links, for example using the following code.

```
if ($row->subject) {
  $titlerow = l($row->subject, "node/{$row->nid}", array('absolute' => TRUE)) . '</br>' // Your code here is not complete.
}
$rows[] = array(
  $titlerow,
  t('Reply posted by !user-link', array('!user-link' => l($row->name, "user/{$row->uid}", array('absolute' => TRUE)))) 
);
```

If you have the Devel module installed, you can see (using the following code) the difference between the output of your code, and mine.

```
print l('Test page', 'node/1') . "\n";
print l('Test page', 'node/1', array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

In my test site, what I get is the following.

```
<a href="/dr72/node/1">Test page</a>
<a href="http://tero.local/dr72/node/1">Test page</a>
```

As side note, remember that the `$options` parameter for `l()` can receive the same values the `$options` parameter for [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) accepts.